# Retrieve values for custom parameters from a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to retrieve values for custom parameters from a string.

Example of string: `aaa[111] bbb[222] ccc[333] ddd[444]`

I need to get the value of `111` for the parameter `aaa`, etc...

The name of parameters are know in advance (here: `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`).

Maybe with regular expressions but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: What should be the end result?

Comment: The end result should be 4 variables (let's say aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd) with the results (here: 111, 222, 333, 444)

Comment: Do you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/47/)

Comment: Not exactly because some parameters may be missing or in another order. Example 1: aaa[111] d[444]  Example 2: ccc[333] bbb[222]. I forgot to mention that in my question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var output = {}; 
var str = "aaa[111] bbb[222] ccc[333] ddd[444]";
str.split(/\s+/).forEach(function(val){ 
  var key = val.substring(0, val.indexOf("[")); 
  var value = val.substring( val.indexOf("[") + 1, val.indexOf("]") ); 
  output[key] = value; 
});

document.body.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(output,0,4);
```

You can use this output variable to get the value against each parameter.

```
output["aaa"]; // outputs 111
```

Comment: That seems very good answer. I test it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `str.match` method.

```js
var str = "aaa[111] bbb[222] ccc[333] ddd[444]";
var strarr=str.match(/\w+\[\w+\]/g);
var val={};
var accounting = [];
for(var i=0;i<strarr.length;i++)
{
    var val1 = strarr[i].match(/\w+(?=\[)/);
  var val2 = strarr[i].match(/\w+(?=\])/);
    val[val1] = val2
    
}

alert(JSON.stringify(val));
```

Comment: Done, thanks for spotting out..

Answer (score 0):

Simple "trick" using `String.replace` function with callback(replacer):

```js
var str = "aaa[111] ddd[444] bbb[222] ccc[333]",
    re = /\b(\w+?)\[(\d+?)\]/g,
    result = {};

str.replace(re, function(m, $1, $2){
    result[$1] = $2;
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,0,4) + "</pre>");
```

Now, the `result` object contains all needed params with appropriate values

Answer (score 0):

A naive regex implementation for this would be `/(\w+)\[([^\]]+)\]/g` which could be used to extract the parameters like this:

```js
var paramRegex = /(\w+)\[([^\]]+)\]/g;

function extractParams(string) {
  var params = {
    aaa: null,
    bbb: null,
    ccc: null
  };

  var match;
  while (match = paramRegex.exec(string)) {
    var name = match[1];
    var value = match[2];

    if (params.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      params[name] = value;
    }
  }

  return params;
}

var test = extractParams(
  "aaa[123] bbb[foo] ccc[some_other_thing] bar[...]"
);

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec)

```js
var string='aaa[111] bbb[222] ccc[333] ddd[444]',
    pattern= /(\S+)\[(\d+)\]/g,
    result = {},
    r;

while ((r = pattern.exec(string)) != null) {
    result[r[1]] = r[2];
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```